# Cocos2D: Two objects of the same class colliding?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Working on game where plates will be falling from top to bottom. Some plates will also "bounce" on the ground and then start moving upwards again. This leads situations where a falling plate collides with a "rising plate".

My problem? I don´t know how to detect this collision.

Since all the plates comes from the same class I can´t write 
`if(CGRectIntersectsRect([self boundingBox], [self boudingBox]))`
since this statement will always be true.

I create the plates with a for-loop:

```
for(i=0; i<9; i++){

 Plate *plate = [Plate initPlate];

}
```

and then just reuse these plates throughout the game.

Any ideas or work arounds on how I detect a collision between two plates? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a class that manages (for example using a NSMutableArray) the set of plates, and instead of checking for collisions on the Plate class you do it on this new class.

Assuming your array is:

```
NSMuttableArray *plateSet
```

You can do this:

```
for (Plate *bouncingPlate in plateSet)
{
    if ([bouncingPlate bouncing])
    {
        for (Plate *fallingPlate in plateSet)
        {
            if (![fallingPlate bouncing])
            {
                /* Check for collision here between fallingPlate and bouncingPlate */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or, more elegantly:

```
for (Plate *bouncingPlate in plateSet)
{
    if (![bouncingPlate bouncing])
    {
        continue;
    }

    for (Plate *fallingPlate in plateSet)
    {
        if ([fallingPlate bouncing])
        {
            continue;
        }
        /* Check for collision here between fallingPlate and bouncingPlate */
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think it´s possible to add the "bouncing" plates in another array, so the collision statement would check if one of the plates is falling and the other is bouncing back up. One falling array and one bouncing array that is!

Comment: I think that is not necessary, the plates should have an attribute that tells if it is bouncing, in the class where you implement the array you just have to check if the bouncing plates collide with the falling plates. Check for the updated answer.

Comment: Just edited the answer. It was relying on a "falling" attribute that is not necessary since if it is not bouncing, it is falling.

Answer (score 0):

yes...you need to add them to a `NSMutableArray` and then just use `ccpDistance` to check collision

something like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<8,i++){
   for (int j=i+1,j<9,j++){
if(ccpDistance([[plates objectAtIndex:i]position],[[plates objectAtIndex:j]position])<plateRadius*2) {
//collision detected
}}}
```

of course this works if plates are circles

for squares use `CGRectIntersectsRect`:

```
 for (int i=0;i<8,i++){
   for (int j=i+1,j<9,j++){
if([plates objectAtIndex:i].visible && [plates objectAtIndex:j].visible &&(CGRectIntersectsRect([[plates objectAtIndex:i]boundingBox],[[plates objectAtIndex:j]boundingBox])) {
//collision detected
}}}
```

Comment: Your using two for-loop´s here, is the first one meant to be the for-loop i used earlier? Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Forget that last comment! I´ve tried out your code in an update, the if-statement returns true every frame. By the way, is there any difference between using a NSMutableArray and a CCArray? Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: I prefer using NSArray or NSSet because it gives me more flexibility. For example when user pauses the game i quickly write the array in a file..to save progress and things like that. As for the collision..which one are you using?, how big are the plates? and..maybe there is a problem in another part of the game and/or in the game logic itself.

Comment: I´m using CGRectIntersectsRect. For some reason the plates all already colliding, all the time. Can the plates collide even if there set to: plate.visble = NO; at init? They don´t have a set "spawning" point either so this doesn´t make any sense at all.

Comment: Hmm, `"property 'visible' not found on object type of id"``

Comment: is Plate a subclass of CCSprite? and if it is..how do you add the sprite itself to Plate class. I mean you use :[CCSprite spriteWithFile..] or [Plate spriteWithFile].

Comment: It´s subclassing CCSprite, yes. The Plate class have a custom init-method that initialises the sprite with a spriteFrameName. Maybe I should mention that I use a batch node do draw the plates. I really appreciate all your help man.

Comment: you haven't answer my question..what method are you using? [CCSprite...] or [Plates ...] because you need to use Plates to subclass properly

Comment: then it should work...the other way i can think of is to make a custom property in plates and in the getter and setter set the opacity to 0 and 255..but then the object will still be drawn on the screen..i seriously don't know without seeing your class and how you use the visibility

Comment: Alright, thanks for helping out anyway. I suggested another work around in the answer above yours. Using one array for the falling plates and one array for "bouncing" plates. Sounds valid?

Comment: it's more complicated that way because when it hits bottom you need to move the object from an array to another, and then redraw it on the screen, and then remove the other from the first array, and you need to add condition for collision on the both arrays, and check if...when you change the arrays..if a collision happens, and other things. With one array you just modify the direction of movement..and that's all. My code should work..i've used something similar so i don't know why it wouldn't.

Comment: Hmm, does the plate really have to be redrawn because of I remove it from an array? If I add it to the array after it has been drawn, is that still the case?

Comment: well you don't have to..but when you'll want to release it from memory it may not release and you'll have a leak